# Translate constraint Check either column not null in spring jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following sql table with CONSTRAINT CHECK. How can I translate this in spring jpa?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myschema`.`product` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `barcode` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `vrcode` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `barcode_UNIQUE` (`barcode` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `vrcode_UNIQUE` (`vrcode` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT CHECK (barcode IS NOT NULL OR vrcode IS NOT NULL))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

I would like to have either one of the column barcode or vrcode must not null.

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "barcode")
    private String barcode;

    @Column(name = "vrcode")
    private String vrcode;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the check on the entity itself, like this

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Check(constraints = "barcode IS NOT NULL OR vrcode IS NOT NULL") 
public class Product implements Serializable {
...
```

Note: `@RequiredArgsConstructor` is already provided with the annotation `@Data`

Comment: How to do if we have multiple checks on different columns (in sql). 
For example : 
`CONSTRAINT CHECK (barcode IS NOT NULL OR vrcode IS NOT NULL)` 
`CONSTRAINT CHECK (name IS NULL AND NOT ( vrcode IS NULL AND barcode IS NULL) )`

Comment: you cannot add more than one @Check so you will have to add all your constraint using () and AND operators. E.g (constraint1) AND (constraint2) AND (constraint3), one constraint represent 1 CONSTRAINT CHECK in sql. If you have too many constraints, I would advice you to check out Java Bean Validation where you can define custom annotations for complex checks to be done on the object.